# Core Data NSManagedObject like a base class

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a base class `@interface BaseMailbox : NSManagedObject` and I have two children of it.
It seems like it's possible to create an object of my class only the next way:

```
BaseMailbox *mailbox;
mailbox = [NSEntityDescription
                                           insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"BaseMailbox"
                                           inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

So it seems like Core Data objects don't support polymorphism?

**EDIT:**

Before to create my mailbox object for example I used:

```
 account = [[GoogleMailbox alloc]
                   initWithFullName
```

and when I called `account.connect` - it was a connection with gmail params.

But now `account` doesnt refer to any of the children object and when I call `account.connect`- it calles base class method.

**EDIT2**

```
BEFORE CORE DATA:

if([_emailAddress.text endsWith:SUFFIX_GOOGLE]){

    account = [[GoogleMailbox alloc]
               initWithFullName:_fullName.text emailAddress:_emailAddress.text password:_password.text];

}else if([_emailAddress.text endsWith:SUFFIX_YAHOO]){

    account = [[YahooMailbox alloc]
               initWithFullName:_fullName.text emailAddress:_emailAddress.text password:_password.text];

}else{
```

..........

```
BOOL success = [account connect]; // GoogleMailbox or YahooMailbox or ...,depending the account refers to.
```

**CORE DATA:**

```
 BaseMailbox* account = [NSEntityDescription
                                      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MailBox"
                                      inManagedObjectContext:context];

    }else{
```

..........

```
  BOOL success = [account connect]; // BaseMailbox
```

Comment: Core Data only requires that any managed object is created by its designated initializer (or the convenience method `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:...`). Can you clarify what you mean by "don't support polymorphism"? (According to http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/polymorphism-is-always-wrong-word.html, "polymorphism" is an often misunderstood term, so describing your actual problem might help.)

Comment: What you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: please see the Edit section

Comment: What is `account.connect`? What class, how is it created? Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking ... Please try to describe your concrete problem, and show the relevant code.

Comment: please see the Edit 2 section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Data entities support an inheritance concept.
An entity "A" can be defined as "Parent Entity" of another entity "B" in the
Data Model Inspector. This is reflected in the corresponding managed object subclasses:
`B` is a subclass of `A`.

So you could define an entity "BaseMailbox" and make that the parent entity of
"GoogleMailbox" and "YahooMailbox". Attributes which are common to all subclasses are
defined in the parent entity.

[image]

Then

```
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"GoogleMailbox"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:context]
```

returns an `GoogleMailbox` object, which is a subclass of `BaseMailBox`.